# Rendering same items with same ids across multiple pages

Tags: mysql, node.js, rendering, ejs, e-commerce

I am figuring out how to render my products across three different pages without adjusting their ids. Currently, the products only render on the home page but I want it on two other pages say About, and Services pages. I am working with NodeJS as my backend framework and ejs as my templating engine. Also, I am propagating my products data from a MySQL database and using a forEach() method to loop through them.

This is my index.ejs file sesction that propagates the data from database:

```
   <% result.forEach(function(product){ %>

        <div class="product_card col-lg-3">
            <img src="images\<%= product.image %>">
            <div class="product_content">
                <p><%= product.name %></p>
                <h5>£<%= product.price %></h5>
                <a href="/singleproduct/<%= product.id %>" role="button">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <% }) %>
```

The get method function extracting the data from database and rendering it to the index page for display:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    let con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.HOST,
        user: process.env.USER,
        password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE
    })
   con.query('SELECT * FROM products', function(err, result){

    res.render('index', {result:result});
   })

})
```

I want these same products rendering on other pages without having to adjust their ids.

Comment: Why can't you just duplicate that code in the other pages?

Comment: When I do that, because I did a res.render to the index route, when I apply same code to different pages it doesn't work. Unless probably create another get function and render it to the other page I want. My issue is won't that alter their unique ids?

Comment: Why would it change IDs? Those come from the database, you're not changing that.